# Assigning one type of object to other type of reference variable not working

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class B{
public:
  B(){}
};
class A
{
public:
A(){}
A(B &b){

}
A(const B &b){
       cout<<"cccddd"<<endl;
}
};
int main()
{
   B b;
   A c(b);
   A a;
   a=b; //ok
   A &ref = b; //error and why???
}
```

why b assigned to a is ok,but b assigned to ref is illegal???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A(const B &b){
       cout<<"cccddd"<<endl;
}
```

This will enable you to convert an object of type `B` into an object of type `A`. However, a reference `T&` cannot be created from another type `L`.

> #### 8.5.3 References [dcl.init.ref]
>
> 1. A variable declared to be a `T&` or `T&&`, that is, “reference to type `T`” (8.3.2), shall be initialized by an object, or function, of type T or by an object that can be converted into a T.
> 2. [...]
> 3. [...]
> 4. Given types “cv1 `T1`” and “cv2 `T2`,” “cv1 `T1`” is reference-related to “cv2 `T2`” if `T1` is the same type as `T2`, or `T1` is a base class of `T2`. “cv1 `T1`” is reference-compatible with “cv2 `T2`” if `T1` is reference-related to `T2` and cv1 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv2 [...].

In your example neither are `A` and `B` the same type, nor is `A` a base class of `B`, thus both classes aren't reference-related.

#### Why won't `A &ref = (A)b` work?

The expression `(A) b` will actually create a temporary, which cannot be bound to a normal reference:

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘A&’ from a temporary of type ‘B’

You would need to a const reference `A const & ref = (A)b` for this.

Comment: another type L?? what's your meaning?

Comment: @huwang: It's generalized. In your case `T` is `A`, and `L` is `B`. They are different classes, and the same rule as for different types apply. The important thing is that `T` is not `L`.

Comment: :but why there is an automatic conversion from a reference to a derived type to a reference to its base type(s) ? although they have different types

Comment: @huwang: Wait, what? Neither `a` nor `b` are references. But if you wait a second I will quote the specific part from the standard.

Comment: but:`#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{};
class B
{
public:
 B(A &a){}
};
int main()
{
 A a;
 B &refb = (B)a;
}`  compilation error too??? why??

Comment: Yes. Have a very good look at the compilation error and try to understand it: "prog.cpp:5: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘B&’ from a temporary of type ‘B’". By using `(B)` you actually create a temporary. I believe this particular question has already been answered on stackoverflow, if not, feel free to open a new question.

Comment: :I feel shame to ask such question